# Accessing Sharepoint 2010 Intranet folder via UNC path

Tags: domain-name-system, network-share, sharepoint-2010

We have this Sharepoint 2010 site with a Document Library that needs to be accessed from a separate system. And this separate system connects to it via a UNC string, such as \intranet\site\folder.

The weird thing is that this works from some computers and server. While others can't resolve the name. And I can't find any correlation for it. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with user permissions either, because I've tried from both my own user as well as domain admin. And it works sometimes, while sometimes it doesn't.

Allthough it does seem to work after ipconfig/renew. As though the DNS name isn't resolved. Could it be related to DNS first and foremost? The sharepoint server has it's own record A in the DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer I believe. Seems it was the WebClient services that was acting up. Also, this services isn't installed by default on Windows 2008 systems. And once it's installed it needs to be set to Automatic start.